# Separating values of JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm new in using JSON and I have trouble extracting data from a parsed JSON object :

I have a getstats.php file that echoes a json encoded result from a mysql query. Here is an example of what the php file returns :

> [{"x":"0","label":"July","y":"23"},{"x":"1","label":"August","y":"58"},{"x":"2","label":"September","y":"78"},{"x":"3","label":"October","y":"77"}]

This is caught by an ajax query in a separate javascript file :

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getstats.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {start : start, end : end},
      success: function(data) {
           //here I deal with the JSON

      }
});
```

So far so good, I can access each values individually (`data[2].month == 'September'`...)

I want to split the variable `data` so I can use the values into a flot chart, so I need something like :

```
 var dataset = [[0,23],[1,58],[2,78],[3,77]];
 var xlabel = [[0,'July'],[1,'August'],[2,'September'],[3,'October']];
```

I can't figure out an easy way to do this (I mean without doing a loop through `data` and extracting the values into new arrays one by one).

Comment: Parsed JSON is just an ordinary JavaScript object. There is no additional magic you can do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you restructure you JSON to represent the two arrays I don't see a different way. Whether you loop yourself or use a helper method from some library or your own code it will have to be traversed.

So that being said your data JSON could have two properties called `PropA` and `PropB` and those two properties would have exactly what you need for your `dataset` and `xlabel` arrays. So instead of looping through data you would just do:

```
dataset = data.PropA
xlabel= data.PropB
```

Comment: +1 agreed, the best solution would to be return the data in the format you are looking for

Comment: I was so focused on the javascript I totally didn't think of changing the JSON format... Thanks !